# How to SET LIMIT in Joomla Database using php?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla3.0

How to SET LIMIT in Joomla Database with PHP? If logged in users who belongs to group 2 I should see only 3 values and if logged in user who belongs to group 6  I should see only 9 values out of n number of data.

```
    <?php 
    $dbo = JFactory::getDBO(); 
    $user=& JFactory::getuser(); 

    $admin = $user->get('username');
    $groups = $user->get('groups');

    foreach($groups as $id) {

     echo "<p>Group ID is:" . $id . "</p>";

      // how to assign the limit ?

    if($id ==2){    
        echo  "<ul id='jchat_conference_userslist'></ul>"; //  3 users
    } elseif($id ==6){  
        echo "<ul id='jchat_conference_userslist'></ul>";   // 9 users  
    }

    }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`setQuery($query,0,4);` is used to limit the query

Comment: the answer you have given for an older version

Comment: can u mention ur database version

Comment: 5.6.36-82.1 this is my version